# Why Is My Website Cannot Be Reviewed In Facebook Debugger?

Tags: facebook, facebook-opengraph

Is there anyone here who had experience like this? I tried to debug my website on facebook debugger but the result is,

"We can't review this website because the content doesn't meet our Community Standards. If you think this is a mistake, please let us know."

My website content is about real estate property listings, how is it possible that it doesn't meet the facebook community standard? I tried to message facebook but I don't have the reply yet. Here is my og properties;

```
<meta property="og:url"           content="http://mysite.epizy.com/" />
<meta property="og:type"          content="website" />
<meta property="og:title"         content="My Realty" />
<meta property="og:description"   content="<?php 
include('config/meta/metadescription.php'); ?>" />
<meta property="og:image"         
content="http://mysite.epizy.com/images/bg_1.jpg" />
```

I have other website running also from infinityfree.net that has no any issues with facebook but I have deleted it last week. Can anyone tell me about what is wrong? Thank you.

Comment: _“how is it possible that it doesn't meet the facebook community standard?”_ - that’s usually what happens, when your site created a “negative user experience”, and people reported it as such. You can’t do much more than report that you consider this a wrongful block - and maybe have some friends do it as well, because a single report is likely not going to do much. _“real estate property listings”_ - that type of sites quite often _are_ spammers, in my experience, posting their listing in groups and on timelines without being asked to …

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I just don't get what was the real issue is. And in the first place, aside from my website, I have facebook pages for each of the developers that I am accredited and I am only posting those listing to each own pages and I never post those to other facebook page. I have another website hosted by 000webhost and it is working very well on facebook.

Comment: I got it working now. I created a blog website on simplesite.com then posted my latest listing and link it from my website hosted by infinityfree and now I can post it to facebook. Just another additional workload for me. It is so frustrating for me because I still never received a reply from facebook about my concern.